# telegram bot api SendPhoto object has photo='null'

Tags: java, api, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I took file_id of the photo by sending this photo to bot, applying this code and copying file_id from the bot response:

```
if(receivedUpdate != null && receivedUpdate.getMessage().hasPhoto())
        {
            String file_id_avoid = receivedUpdate.getMessage().getPhoto().stream().findFirst().orElse(null).getFileId();
            sendMessage_text(file_id_avoid);
        }
```

Then I am using this:

```
messageToBeSent_PHOTO.setPhoto("AgADAgADCagxG29QQEpt1IJFo-l3xVToDw4ABAopYoYfhAlE7P0AAgI").setCaption(null);
            sendMessage_photo();
```

and it says:

org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiValidationException: Photo can't be empty in method: SendPhoto{chatId='230164432', photo='null', caption='null', replyToMessageId=null, replyMarkup=null, isNewPhoto=false}

Comment: Try using the API in your browser with the sendPhoto method and appropriate arguments and see if it works there.

Comment: The problem was the typo in the code: the same method which sends photo was located before initialization of the photo and I couldn't see it. W/o that typo it works well.The problem is solved. Ex dee